# MongoDB: Faster alternative to a basic $geoIntersects query

Tags: query, mongodb

I've got a whole bunch of political boundaries defined in a MongoDB collection, which are (as you might guess) very complex polygons, with thousands of points.

One of the queries I need to run is to retrieve all the boundaries which overlap a rectangular map extent. Right now I'm just running a `$geoIntersects` query on the polygons, which are `2dsphere`-indexed.

Since it's OK if the occasional polygon which doesn't actually overlap the map gets included by accident, I know I could just add a bounding-box property to each document which contains a simple rectangular boundary that includes the whole polygon, then index and run my `$geoIntersects` query against the boxes. But I'd prefer, if possible, to avoid having to add another property to the documents.

Is there a simpler/more efficient way to do this? Or is the bounding box idea the best option?

Comment: this question is 4 years old but the issue still is present: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20843